Estoy haciendo una script con html para subir un archivo excel y pasar los datos a una hoja de calculo de google, pero da error
Tengo un gódigo .gs y html para pasar unos datos de una hoja excel a una hoja de calculo en una carpeta de Drive.
He copiado parte del código de uno ya existente que hace mas o menos lo mismo y he cambiado algunos parámetros, pero no me funciona. Siempre sale el error de que no se ha podido procesar el archivo o no se ha encontrado.
La cosa es que tengo una parte del código donde copia el archivo Excel en la carpeta que tengo creada en el Drive y funciona. Supongo que el problema es en las siguientes lineas, pero sigo sin poder hacer que funcione. Supongo que tengo todos los permisos ya que la carpeta y todo la he creado yo. Esto es para mi trabajo, y el código que ya estaba hecho, obviamente, funciona.
Aquí os paso el código:
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index.html");
}

function upload(e) {
  if (!e || !e.file) {
    return "No se ha detectado ningún archivo";
  }

  var destination_id = '1nTEN0yYs-iDb0_ilr9-M2aqKzs5sIqFM'; 
  var file = e.file;
  var contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
  var fileBlob = file.getAs(contentType);
  var fileName = file.getName();

  // Check if file with the same name already exists in the destination folder
  var existingFiles = destination.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
    var existingFile = existingFiles.next();
    existingFile.setTrashed(true);
  }

  // Create new file with the same name in the destination folder
  var newFile = destination.createFile(fileBlob).setName(fileName);

  // Convert the Excel file to Google Sheets format
  var fileId = newFile.getId();
  var blob = newFile.getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: newFile.getName(),
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
  };
  var fileConverted = Drive.Files.copy(resource, fileId, {convert: true});
  var spreadsheetId = fileConverted.id;

  // Get the spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Set the spreadsheet locale to avoid number format issues
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setSpreadsheetLocale('en_US');
  
  // Get the data from the sheet
  var b2Value = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var sheets = {
    'SGES': 'DATOS'
  };

  var targetSheetName;
  for (var sheetName in sheets) {
    if (b2Value.indexOf(sheets[sheetName]) !== -1) {
      targetSheetName = sheetName;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (targetSheetName) {
    // Get the target sheet and clear its contents
    var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
    targetSheet.getRange("A1:P").clearContent();
    
    // Copy data from the source sheet to the target sheet
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 16);
    targetRange.setValues(sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 16).getValues());
  }

  // Close the temporary spreadsheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).setTrashed(true);
  
  // Delete the uploaded file and the converted file
  newFile.setTrashed(true);
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setTrashed(true);
  
  return "Archivo procesado correctamente";
}

function limpiarHojaPromise() {
  var targetSheetNames = ['DATOS'];
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var message = "";

  targetSheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    var targetSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (targetSheet) {
      // Get the range to clear (from column A to Y)
      var range = targetSheet.getRange("A:Y");
      // Clear the range
      range.clearContent();
      message += "Hoja " + sheetName + " borrada correctamente.\n";
    } else {
      message += "No se encontró la hoja " + sheetName + ".\n";
    }
  });

  return message;
} 

Os dejo el html tambien:
<html>
<head>
 
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400&display=swap');


        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #3498db;
            font-family: "Roboto", "sans serif";
            justify-content: center; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
            align-items: center; /* Centrar verticalmente */
            height: 100vh; /* Ajustar al 100% del viewport height */
        }


        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          padding: 10px 10px;
        }


        table {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
        }


        th {
          background-color: #0072CE;
          color: white;
        }


        td {
          font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        }


        .button {
            position: flex; /* Ocupar el mismo espacio para que tengan el mismo tamaño */
            background-color: #FF8300; /* Color de fondo naranja */
            color: white; /* Color del texto en el botón */
            padding: 5px 5px; /* Espaciado interno del botón */
            border: none; /* Sin borde */
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar el cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
            font-size: 15px; /* Tamaño de fuente 15px */
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        }


        .button-2 {
            position: flex; /* Ocupar el mismo espacio para que tengan el mismo tamaño */
            background-color: #0072CE; /* Color de fondo azul DKT */
            color: white; /* Color del texto en el botón */
            padding: 5px 5px; /* Espaciado interno del botón */
            border: none; /* Sin borde */            
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar el cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
            font-size: 15px; /* Tamaño de fuente 15px */
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        }


        .log {
          margin-top: 1rem;
          border: 0px solid #ccc;
          padding: 1rem;
          max-height: 0px; /* Ajustar altura máxima para que no ocupe demasiado espacio */
          overflow:hide;
          width: 100%; /* Ajustar el ancho para que ocupe todo el contenedor */
          font-family: monospace;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <!-- TITULO DE PAGINA -->
    <div class="brand clearfix" style="background-color: #3498db;">
      <img href="" class="logo" sizes="3px 3px">
      <h4 class="text-white" style="margin:25px 0px 0px 25px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;"><b>CAPACIDADES UNIFICADAS</b></h4>
      <img href="" class="logo" sizes="3px 3px">
    </div>


    <div style="padding: 10px; padding-top: 1%;"></div>
    <div class="form-row"></div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <span class="form-group col-md-2"></span>
      <span class="form-group col-md-3"></span>  
    </div>
    <div class="form-row"></div>


    <!-- SUBIDA DE ARCHIVOS -->
    <div class="card" style="padding: 30px;">
     
      <H6><strong><i>SUBIDA DE ARCHIVOS</i></strong></H6>
     
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <p> Selecciona el archivo </p>
            <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="button" type="button"  value="️ Borrar los datos" onclick="limpiarSheet()">
            <input class="button-2" type="button" value=" Subir el archivo" onclick="uploadFile(this.form)">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="log" id="log"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  <script>
    function uploadFile() {
        var form = document.querySelector('form'); // Obtener el formulario actual
        var button = form.querySelector('.button-2'); // Obtener el botón dentro del formulario
        var log = document.getElementById("log");


        button.value = 'Procesando archivo...';
        button.disabled = true;


        log.innerText += "> Procesando archivo";
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(function() {
            button.value = ' Subir otro archivo';
            button.disabled = false;
            log.innerText += " > Hecho\n";
            alert("Archivo procesado correctamente");
          })
          .withFailureHandler(function() {
            button.value = 'Reintentar ';
            button.disabled = false;
            log.innerText += " > Error\n";
            alert("Ha ocurrido un error. No se ha detectado un archivo o no ha podido ser procesado.");
          })
          .upload(form);
      }
    // Agrega una variable para rastrear el estado de procesamiento
    var isProcessing = false;


    function limpiarSheet() {
      if (isProcessing) {
        return; // Si la función ya está en progreso, no hacer nada
      }


      isProcessing = true;


      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      log.innerText += "> Borrando datos";


      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function() {
          isProcessing = false;
          log.innerText += " > Hecho\n";
          alert("Los datos se han borrado correctamente");
          resetButton();
        })
        .withFailureHandler(function() {
          isProcessing = false;
          log.innerText += "> Error al reiniciar";
          alert("Ha ocurrido un error");
          resetButton();
        })
        .limpiarHojaPromise();
    }


    // Función para restablecer el estado del botón
    function resetButton() {
      var button = document.querySelector('input[value="Limpiar"]');
      button.value = 'Reset';
      button.disabled = false;
    }


  </script>
</body>
</html>


Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Cuando se pide ayuda para resolver un error, debe de incluirse un [mcve] y el mensaje de error textual. En este caso el código hace uso del Servicio Avanzado de Drive pero no se menciona si lo has agregado a tu proyecto. El "mcve" debe incluir todos los detalles relevantes para reproducir el error.
